# How to avoid recreating view on onCreate on Android?

Tags: android

I have a `FragmentActivity` that shows a contacts list.

Here is my `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_human_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.human_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;

        // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
        // 'activated' state when touched.
        ((HumanListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.human_list))
                .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null || !savedInstanceState.getBoolean("displayed_contacts"))
        displayContacts();
}
```

My `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("displayed_contacts", true);
}
```

And I'm not sure if this is relevant, but here's my `displayContacts` just in case:

```
private void displayContacts() {

    // Init variables
    String[] SelectColumns = new String[] { Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, Contacts.PHOTO_URI };
    String rawContactID, displayName, phoneNumber;
    InputStream thumbnailPhoto;
    Cursor c, infoC;

    // Outer cursor (fetches all contact IDs)
    c = getContentResolver().query(
            Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            SelectColumns,
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1 ",
            null,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);

    Log.v(getPackageName(), "Found " + (c != null ? c.getCount() : "0") + " contacts");
    try {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // Columns
                rawContactID    = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SelectColumns[0]));
                displayName     = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SelectColumns[1]));
                String[] selectPhone = {CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

                thumbnailPhoto = openThumbnail(Long.valueOf(rawContactID));

                infoC = getContentResolver().query(
                        CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        selectPhone,
                        CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[] {rawContactID},
                        null
                    );
                infoC.moveToFirst();
                phoneNumber = infoC.getString(0);

                // Adds items to ListView
                HumanContent.addItem(new HumanContent.HumanItem(rawContactID, displayName, phoneNumber != "n/a" ? phoneNumber : "", thumbnailPhoto));
                Log.v(getPackageName(), "Cursor position: " + c.getPosition() + ", contact ID: " + rawContactID);
                infoC.close();
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }
        displayed_contacts = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getPackageName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now here's the thing:

When I use the back key to exit the application, and then open it again via the icon; the list recreates itself even though it is saved in memory: so I get a double list of contacts on the same view.

`savedInstanceState` is null in that case, so the if condition is reached, but in reality the view already has my previous contact list. What gives? How can I avoid recreating the list? I already tried using instance variables instead, but to no avail.

I'd also like to avoid recreating the list 100% of the times - if I can reuse the existing view, awesome.

Comment: Using the back key to exit the application actually destroys the application - it doesn't pause it.

Comment: Yeah, but then the view state is somehow resumed - I open the app again, and the contact list already exists in there, which I then proceed to recreate because `savedInstanceState` is null.

Comment: That's not guaranteed @ninetwozero

Comment: Can you just check the contents of the list? If contacts are present, don't bother loading, etc.

Comment: Well, how can I access the list? I'm loading it with an adapter and a fragment

Comment: Couple of things: Strings are compared using the `String#equals(String)` method. `phoneNumber != "n/a"` isn't correct for your purpose. Second, I see that you are using `displayed_contacts` as a boolean flag. But then, you have `savedInstanceState.putBoolean("displayed_contacts", true);` in your `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` method. It should be `savedInstanceState.putBoolean("displayed_contacts", displayed_contacts);`.... (contd.)

Comment: Noted about the string, but for the boolean... I'm assuming it displayed the contacts list so when I save the state I can always just use true. The problem is that it's never true when I return to the app

Comment: (contd.) .. From the info you have given, its hard to trace the problem which I believe is `displayContacts()` being called twice in your activity's starting phase. An easy hack (not a fix) would be to clear the data structure(list/array) that you assign to the ListView just before you get into the `do-while` loop.

Comment: "So, what you get on launching the app from the launcher is a brand new instance" which is what I hoped would happen, but somehow it still saves my previous list! Why is that?

Comment: Brand new instance is a bit misleading. OS is not saving your previous list. It just hasn't been destroyed yet. Same with your activity. Immediately after leaving the activity using the back button, the activity is in the paused state, with its resources intact. `HumanContent` (not sure what it is) still holds your data from before the back button was pressed, and hence the duplication.

Comment: This should be a design consideration for you. As much as a developer would like to re-use instead of re-create/re-gather, the user wants to see updated data. Keeping the worst-case scenario in mind (that every time the user leaves your app, s/he adds a few contact before returning; be this through the Home button, Back button, a Phone call), you should re-gather the contacts whenever your app resumes. So, data acquisition and/or update should go inside `onResume` because its called every which way the user starts or resumes your app.

Comment: Since you are delegating the task of holding and maintaining the data to `HumanContact`, the solution has to be implemented there. Add a (static) method in HumanContact that clears out the list. And call `HumanContact.emptyTheList()` before starting the `do-while` loop.

Comment: Have you considered using `setRetainInstance(true)` inside your HumanFragment?

Comment: @user2558882 this might be slow for the user to re-create every time. I'm considering a refresh button for immediate refresh, and maybe storing local copies of contacts for faster use, but it's still in early stages.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski how would that work?

Comment: I do not belieave setRetainInstance will have any effect in this case. This is not a case of your Activity being stopped and started, or even recreated. It is being entirely destroyed and a new instance is being created. Even with setRetainInstance you're going to see a new instance of your Fragment being created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the reason your savedInstanceState is null - The system only saves state of activities that are destroyed due to system constraints. If you back out of an Activity it is destroyed for good, and no state will be saved.

Relevant docs:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

> When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the
>   activity finishes itself,  the system's concept of that Activity
>   instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity
>   is no longer needed. However, if the system destroys the activity due
>   to system constraints (rather than normal app behavior), then although
>   the actual Activity instance is gone, the system remembers that it
>   existed such that if the user navigates back to it, the system creates
>   a new instance of the activity using a set of saved data that
>   describes the state of the activity when it was destroyed.

So, it seems like your particular problem is that while your Activity is gone, your static HumanContact class is still in memory, and your new Activity is loading it with another copy of your contacts.

There are a couple ways you could solve this. First, you could implement a method on HumanContent to clear out all its items, and call it whenever you launch a new instance of your Activity. This would have the benefit of ensuring your data is up to date, but would mean you have to reload your contacts.

Secondly, if you wanted to truly avoid reloading the data, I'd recommend creating some sort of cache for the contacts that is independent of the Activity. You should consider your Activity as fairly transient, it can and will be destroyed and recreated frequently, whereas a cache can persist.

HumanContent seems to be filling this responsibility already, to an extent. You're using it to store your data, and it is persisting beyond the lifecycle of your Activity. You could additionally add a method to it that checks to see if it has contacts loaded, and if not loads them itself. This way it has complete control over loading and caching your data, and Activities can be responsible solely for the display of this data. Be careful with this type of solution that you're not storing too much data in memory, that you're reloading your cache anytime you expect your data to have changed, and be aware that your process might be restarted by the system in some cases, so your cache must be prepared to reload your data in case it is destroyed.

As for preserving your Views, if the user is backing out of your Activity then the finish() is being called, and your Activity is going to be destroyed. Remember, in this case the system no longer has any concept of the Activity, so there will be no way to preserve these views for reuse.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So how would I do the caching then? Also potentially, since the `HumanContent` is being saved by itself, if I put a class variable there to check whether contacts have been loaded, potentially that would mean that while the data itself is preserved, so would my variable so I could use that to my advantage?

Comment: Your cache could probably take the form of an array holding your HumenItem objects stored in HumenContent. I would create a method on HumenContent that when called, checks its HumenItems array to see if it is empty, and if it is loads the contacts, but otherwise does nothing. Then I would call this method from my Activity every time it launches. This way your contacts will be preserved in HumenContent, they're available for the Activity to use, but are not recreated.

Comment: To answer your second question, yes, you could create a boolean variable on HumanContent that stores whether or not the contacts have been loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Its simple. follow these steps in your Activity

- Declare your **listview object** and **listview_adapter object** in side your Activity class.
- Initialise your **listview object** and **listview_adapter object** in *OnCreate()* method and  add the contents in your displayContacts().

Then definitely you wont get content replication.

Comment: I'll note that since in your specific case the Activity is being destroyed as well as the Fragment, caching your view and adapter on the Activity will not solve your problem unless they are stored statically. Caching them on the Activity would be equivalent to calling setRetainInstance(true) on the fragment - it will only be effective when the Activity is being recreated not when a new instance is being created from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way to achieve this is to do a Nullcheck 
i.e.

```
if(yourcomponent==null) {
    initializecomponent();
}
```

That may prevent your views from recreating.

Answer (score 1):

It is always adviced to use caching to retain the data . as mentiond by Groucho u can go with storage options
Check below link for details.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue once. I am not sure how legitimate this is but the code I have used is below and it fixed a lot:

```
private static ViewGroup view1;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mCurrentActivity = getActivity();
        if (view1 == null) {
            settleFragment(inflater);
        } else {
            if (view1.getParent() != null && view1.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ((ViewGroup) view1.getParent()).removeView(view1);
            }
        }
        return view1;
    }
```

You can adapte `settleFragment(inflater);` method with yours.
The magic is about static variable named `view1`. Once the fragment is initialised it is filled up with the data. The other instances of Fragments will simply rip apart `view1` from its ex-parent and will paste it on themself.

It is pretty fast with respect to file storage cache since the object is kept in ram. If OS garbage collects the object, static variable will be null again and while recreating the view no duplicates will occur.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can stop `onCreate` function from executing. However, you could apply a work-around to avoid duplicate list, you could remove all items from the listview and then let it repopulate the listview.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onPause ()
{
    super.onPause();
    //...........
}

@Override
public void onStop ()
{
    super.onPause();
    //............
}
```

Check if you can use these methods in your fragments ?

Answer (score 0):

when you are done with loading of the data in displayContacts(), you can save a flag(displayed_contacts) in shared preferences. In onCreate() check the preference value, and call your displayContacts() accordingly.

Comment: But when the activity dies completely, that value will remain true.

Comment: you can implement ondestroy() method and there you can reset the flag.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem while using Fragments.

We have existing methods as stated above. If you are finding yourself in difficult position for using that then you can try as mentioned below :-

- Initiate a Boolean value with false.
- Set that Boolean value to true after you get your data.
- Now on re-initiate of your OnCreate() check for that Boolean value to be true or false. if false then you need to pull that data again else you need not to get that data. Put condition for same.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to check controller therefor.

Instead of that try to check value you stored.
First take one variable as Bundle.
Save it in onCreate method.

```
Bundle bdlSaveInstant;   // Declare at top before onCreate() method.
/* Initialise in onCreate() method. After 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_human_list);
bdlSaveInstant = savedInstanceState;
*/

@override
onBackPressed()
{
  bdlSaveInstant.putBoolean("displayed_contacts", true);
}

@override
onDestroy()
{
  bdlSaveInstant.putBoolean("displayed_contacts", true);
}
```

Try this will work.

Answer (score 0):

In your on create method just clear your list.Because every time it will go to on create method and make list clear(which) is your previous data loading.

OR

check your list if(list.size==null) then call your API otherwise in else block (list.setAdapter).

hope it will work.