# In Fragments, Instances are not getting saved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Please have a look at the below code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InputFragment extends Fragment {


    private SeekBar daysAsCustomerSeek;

    private View view;

    //Following variables will save the application state and load back
    //on resume

    private final String DAYS_AS_CUSTOMER_VALUE_HOLDER = "days as customer value";




    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Intializing instance variables
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input, container,false);



        daysAsCustomerSeek = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.days_as_customer_seekbar);

        //Set default max values
        daysAsCustomerSeek.setMax(210);

        return view;

    }

    //This method will save the instances
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle)
    {

        savedInstanceStateBundle.putInt(DAYS_AS_CUSTOMER_VALUE_HOLDER, daysAsCustomerSeek.getProgress());


    }

    //This method will restore the instances
    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceStateBundle);

        if(savedInstanceStateBundle!=null)
        {

            daysAsCustomerSeek.setProgress(savedInstanceStateBundle.getInt(DAYS_AS_CUSTOMER_VALUE_HOLDER));

        }
    }

}
```

The problem is when I turn the device or navigate back to this fragment, non of its states were saved! Instead, everything was recreated! Why is this? Why this code is not showing the state?

Comment: Check out this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019381/how-to-avoid-recreating-view-on-oncreate-on-android/20329356#20329356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceStateBundle);
```

in `onSaveInstanceState` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the case is, it do not restore values when the device orientation changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
someFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
```