# Resume Issue in ViewPager with Tabs

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I am having an issue in `ViewPager`with `Tabs`having `Fragments`. I have my `Home Activity` that has a **ViewPager** with **Tabs**. For each Tab there is a **Fragment**. There are 3 sets of data coming from service when we start the application. The requirement is when I do changes for these sets of data in some other activities, I should be able to see the changes in the `Home Activity`, that means the service calls are to be done again in each of these `Fragments`, which is why I am doing all this part in `onResume()`.

**Required Output is :**
When coming back to HomeActivity(that has the tabs) from another child activity, the service calls should be done.

When hitting on Load More button in any of the tab, the service call associated with that fragment or Tab should be done.

When moving between the Tabs, service calls should not be done, instead the data has to be loaded from Database.

**Current Output is :**
Since I kept all the service calls for those Tabs in onResume() of the associated Fragment, the first and second requirement is met.

When it comes to third requirement, the output is same as the first one i.e., its making service calls which should not happen.

**Problem :** How to identify if user is moving between the Tabs or if he is coming from child activity. This service calls happening while moving between Tabs is causing performance issues. Please help me with this, I have no idea about how to proceed to overcome this performance issue. Thanks.

Comment: Check out my comments over here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019381/how-to-avoid-recreating-view-on-oncreate-on-android/20329356#20329356 .Hope it helps.

Comment: Check out my comments over here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019381/how-to-avoid-recreating-view-on-oncreate-on-android/20329356#20329356 .Hope it helps.